# Avoiding timeout with long API requests in redux-saga react

Tags: reactjs, express, amazon-s3, fetch, multer

I am working on a React.js application with an express backend. The React application is using `whatwg-fetch` to post a csv file to the backend application. The backend then makes some changes to the file, uploads to S3 and returns the S3 url to the React application for download.

I'm running into timeout issues because the csv modification is taking too long. Is there a workaround for this? I thought about making another GET request every 30 seconds to a different route in order to check if the csv file is finished being modified.

Any suggestions on the best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up returning a time estimate of how long the task would take to complete based upon previous recorded data.

Then I creating a route to monitor the status of the task and get the results of the task. I then started calling the monitoring route a few seconds before the estimated time of completion and then retrieved the data from the same route when finished.